# Derivations vs automorphisms of deformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

Let $A$ be a ring, and $p : R'\rightarrow R$ a surjection of $A$-algebras with kernel $I$ a square zero ideal - ie $I^2 = 0$.

Let $f,g : R'\rightarrow R'$ be automorphisms of $R'$ over $R$ (ie, $pf = pg = p$), then it is easy to check that $f-g : R'\rightarrow R'$ has image in $I$, and actually defines an $A$-linear derivation, ie an element of $Der_A(R',I)$. Here we probably want to assume that $f,g$ are also $A$-linear.

Now let $f\in\text{Aut}_A(R')$ respecting the map $p : R'\rightarrow R$, and $D\in Der_A(R',I)$. Must $f+D$ also be an automorphism of $R'$?

If not, what are the "minimal reasonable assumptions" we need to impose for this to be true?

I can show that $f+D : R'\rightarrow R'$ is a homomorphism of $R$-algebras, but am having trouble proving bijectivity.

Variations of this are given in Hartshorne's "Deformation theory", where it's given as exercise 5.2, and in Sernesi's book "Deformations of Algebraic Schemes", where it's "Lemma 1.2.6", but he doesn't actually prove that $f+D$ is an automorphism.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by automorphism of $R'$ over $R$? $R'$ is not necessarily an $R$-algebra.

Comment: @Mohan Let $p$ be the morphism $R'\rightarrow R$, then I want the automorphism $f$ to satisfy $pf = p$. This is what allows me to say that the difference of two such automorphisms has image in $I$. (I've edited to clarify). Thanks for the question.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Well the map $p$ doesn't give $R'$ an $R$-algebra structure, since it goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: Right, nevermind.

Comment: Anyways, typically $Der_A(R',I)$ is the tangent space at $f$ of the space of morphisms of $R$-algebras, i.e. they represent *infinitesimal* deformations. The obstruction to being able to extend an infinitesimal deformation to a *formal* one is usually contained in the second cohomology of a complex. Finally, you need to determine if a formal deformation actually makes sense to get a "real" deformation.

Comment: As the space of morphisms of $R$-algebras is affine, the integration of the infinitesimal deformation $D$ actually gives $f+D$, but this is not generally the case in deformation theory.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Do you really mean morphisms of $R$-algebras? Note that $R'$ is generally not an $R$-algebra. What do you mean "integration of the infinitesimal deformation $D$ actually gives $f+D$"? Also I'm not sure how this addresses my original question >.>

Comment: Sorry, it should be of $A$-algebras. It is meant to be a general remark about deformation theory. It addresses your question in the part that says that "The obstruction to being able to extend an infinitesimal deformation to a formal one is usually contained in the second cohomology of a complex."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the generality you state, the answer is no, the map $f+D$ need not be a bijection.

Here is an ad-hoc example. Let $A=R$ be a field and let $R'$ be the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables $e_i, i\geq 1$ with the relations $e_ie_j=0$ for all $i,j$. Then we have a natural surjection $p:R'\to R$ and the kernel $I$ is the $A$-vector space generated by the $e_i$s and $I^2=0$. Any element in $R'$ can be written uniquely as $\alpha+\sum a_ie_i$ with $\alpha, a_i\in A$, and the sum is finite. Consider the derivation $D:R'\to I$ given by $D(\alpha+\sum a_ie_i)=\sum a_ie_{i+1}$. Then the map $I+D:R'\to R'$ where $I$ is the identity map is not onto. One easily checks that the element $e_1$ is not in the image of this map.

In deformation theory, one of the natural conditions that can be imposed to make everything work is not to take an arbitrary derivation $D:R'\to I$, but take a derivation $D:R\to I$ (note that $I$ is an $R$-module) and then consider it as a derivation from $R'$ using $p$. Then, $D\circ D=0$ and you will have $f+D$ a bijection as you desire. There may be other conditions which might yield the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply. I'll accept your answer, but I think that perhaps the right question to ask is - Is it possible to describe the derivations which appear as the difference of two automorphisms which are $A$-linear and induce the identity on $R$?